# When I use searching function of my checkable combobox and check a result from filter, the line edit cannot be updated

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox, qlineedit

The problem occurs when I use the searching function. Checking from the searching result cannot update the GUI.

i.e. when I search '1' I can get the correct searching result

[image: ex1]

and check the box of '11', get the incorrect GUI of just '1',

[image: ex2]

However, using self.lineEdit().text() I can get the correct result '1;11'. I tried repaint(), update(), and qapp.processEvents() but failed.

As shown in picture, I use .settext but no response in GUI but when I print the text of the editor it's correct.

[image: ex3]

Here is my code. Thanks.

```
class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, items, parent=None):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.items = items
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

        self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        self.addItems(self.items)
        self.lineEdit().selectAll()

        self.model().itemChanged.connect(self.show2)
        self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.filter)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)

    def filter(self, text):
        cur_text = text.split(';')[-1]
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString(cur_text)
        for i in range(len(self.items)):
            item = self.model().item(i, 0)
            if cur_text == self.items[i]:
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            else:
                continue

    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
            self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))

    def addItems(self, items):
        for item in items:
            if item == items[0]:
                self.addItem2(item)
            else:
                self.addItem(item)

    def addItem2(self, item):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).addItem(item)

    def addItem(self, item):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).addItem(item)
        item = self.model().item(self.count()-1,0)
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

    def show2(self):
        show = ''
        for i in self.Selectlist():
            show += i + ';'
        #self.lineEdit().clear()
        self.lineEdit().setText(show)


    def Selectlist(self):
        Outputlist = []
        for i in range(len(self.items)):
            item = self.model().item(i,0)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                Outputlist.append(item.text())
            else:
                continue
        return Outputlist
```

Comment: For me it works correctly on Linux with Qt 5.13.2, python 3.8. You could indicate the characteristics of your environment like python version, pyqt5, OS, etc.

Comment: Qt 5.12, python 3.7 in Windows. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a bug from that old version of PyQt5, try updating.

Comment: another question, which version of your sip package? Once I tried to update but my sip package seems not matched.

Comment: You must first update [python-sip](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-sip). I am use `PyQt5              5.13.2   
PyQt5-sip          12.7.0`

Comment: I updated but it doesn't work. Issue happens when you select item from searching result but not from common use. It works for you, right?

Comment: Okay, I see .... With what you say I can reproduce the problem

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. It's my first time to post a question, so... I tried lots of methods but the GUI cannot be updated.

Comment: Please do not put noise in your question because instead of attracting attention you will get the opposite.

Comment: sorry for that.